# Why is shipping being added to my PayPal IPN response?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Why is shipping being added to my IPN response?  Th is has worked for years but all off a sudden some of our IPN requests are containing shipping parameters like the one below for 17.01  We never send anything in regards to shipping.  This should of been a gross amount of 567.01 (which was regular price of $550.00 plus $17.01 processing fee).  It then adds another 17.01 as shipping to get this $584.02 below.  Does PayPal have a way to add shipping on their side outside of any third party redirects?

```
mc_gross=584.02&invoice=926454&protection_eligibility=Eligible&payer_id=test&payment_date=08%3A27%3A24+Mar+05%2C+2023+PST&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&first_name=test&mc_fee=12.11&notify_version=3.9&custom=926454&payer_status=unverified&business=test%40yahoo.com&quantity=1&verify_sign=test&payer_email=test2%40outlook.com&txn_id=test&payment_type=instant&last_name=test&receiver_email=test%40yahoo.com&payment_fee=12.11&shipping_discount=0.00&insurance_amount=0.00&receiver_id=test&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=test&discount=0.00&mc_currency=USD&item_number=&residence_country=US&receipt_id=test&shipping_method=Store+Pickup&transaction_subject=&payment_gross=584.02&shipping=17.01&ipn_track_id=test
```

Answer (score 0):

If shipping is in a PayPal IPN message, that means it is part of the PayPal transaction.

If shipping is part of a PayPal transaction and that transaction is of type [legacy PayPal Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/gs-PayPalPaymentsStandard/), the shipping could be coming from the PayPal account's [profile shipping and tax](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/ProfileAndTools/#link-calculateshippingchargesautomatically).

If it is not coming from profile shipping and tax that has been set up in the PayPal account, then it must have been specified at transaction time, as part of the button or form/data post that redirected the payer from your site to PayPal.

---

All of the above (including the use of IPN itself, which should be deprecated soon) applies to very old integrations using ~20-year-old technology. If at all possible, any new development should upgrade to a [current PayPal Checkout Integration.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) which is several generations newer and better in every respect.